# Run/Build grayed out in Monodevelop

Tags: build, monodevelop, linux-mint

What the title says. All options in the "Build" tab are grayed out, and run and debug are grayed out in the "Run" tab. I can fix it by giving mono root, but I'm not too keen on having that as a permanent solution.

I have tried creating a new "Hello world" solution just for testing, tried different project file formats(vs 20xx, mono 1.0), reinstalling mono, installing/uninstalling monodevelop-debugger-gdb...

I've been able to run programs before, no idea what happened.

Using linux mint 12 and monodevelop 2.6

Any other info you might need?

Comment: Maybe related to [this question on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/358562/monodevelop-run-button-grayed-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you upgrade to the latest Monodevelop version (3.04). In past releases there was a little bug that allowed what you describe to happen. In my experience it was project specific, meaning, when happened, happened only in one project, usually the last one I was working on.

In the meantime here is a simple workaround to use when that problem happens: 
When that happened to me in the past (using version Monodevelop 2.6 on Ubuntu) I found that if I open, compile and run **successfully** another project, and then go back to try and compile the problematic project (in which the 'Build' options were greyed out) - the problem is solved and all 'Build' menu options become be available again.

I don't know what the bug was, but as I mentioned above, I did not experience the same bug in Monodevelop 3.04, so I recommend you upgrade.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I haven't found mono 3.04 for ubuntu, I'll try to download and compile the source code

Comment: You can also use a PPA and add it to your sources list. See in the following link: https://launchpad.net/~keks9n/+archive/monodevelop-latest. Compiling from source will work as well of course.